# Limits of iterated integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

The region for my iterated integral is restricted by $y = 0$, $x=1$, and $y=x$. My book says that if we look at the region as horizontally simple and make horizontal rectangles, we have the integral $$\int_0^1 \int_y^1 f(x, y) dxdy$$

I understand how $y$ is bounded between $0$ and $1$ and how $x$ is bounded betnwwe $x=1$ and $x=y$, but can't we just as well say that $x$ (the "height") of the rectangles is bounded by $0$ and $x=y$, and have $$\int_0^1 \int_0^y f(x, y) dxdy$$

Is the second representation correct as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite. The integral you've defined is on the other side of $y = x$ from intended. In the original, $x \ge y$ always. In yours $x \le y$ always.

But it is the same as $$\int_0^1 \int_0^x f(x, y) dydx$$